# Extract month from timestamp mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb like that:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ece47aa6510a611b47aac5a"),
    "array" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ece47aa6510a611b47aac6e"),
            "timestamp" : "1470420945250",
        }, 
        {
           "_id" : ObjectId("5ece47aa6510a611b47a8895"),
           "timestamp" : "1470420945250"
        },
        {..},
        {..}
     ]
```

I am trying to make a query to count how many months from timestamp are January for example. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TVL05eMeqLM)

[mongoplayground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oTqoK-3rfBf) => Contains the count, just change the $match around

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$array"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      timestamp: {
        $toDate: "$array.timestamp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      month: {
        $month: {
          date: "$timestamp"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You may add a timezone field inside $month.

Comment: It works fine in your example but the problem is that in my db the timestamp is a string. For example "timestamp" : "1470420945250". So it occurs an error like this:  "Error parsing date string '1470420945250'; 12: Unexpected character '0'"

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/